# IP subnet with extra information outside of BGP and RIPE database

Tags: bgp, arin, ripe

I'm trying to look into the sources of some whois services that can provide more information than BGP and RIPE databases.

Example: If I lookup the IP 104.234.88.128 in https://whoer.net/checkwhois I can see this IP is managed by Rackdog LLC under AT&T ASN.

But when I look into the RIPE database, this information is not found, same with ARIN database where it states this IP belongs to IPXO
https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-234-0-0-2/pft?s=104.234.88.128
and there is no mention of Rackdog nor AT&T.

Where is this information coming from? Is there another database for Internet objects outside of these?

Comment: The official lists are by IANA and the five RIRs. Sometimes, companies get acquired or sell networks without doing it correctly by getting RIR permission to transfer the network(s) to the new owner, so the RIR databases do not get properly updated. The reason for that is that a company, even one that acquired another company, is required to justify getting the network(s).

Comment: @RonMaupin understood, do you know which object would then describe the ISP and the organization? Is this information like IP address and zip code in RIPE or the RIRs?

Comment: RIPE _is_ one of the five RIRs (AFRINIC, APNIC, ARIN, LACNIC, and RIPE). IANA gives the RIRs addressing, and they assign it to companies. Not all of the companies are ISPs, and at that level, you should not even try to distinguish ISPs from other companies because they are all equal with their own ASes, and they can connect to whichever other companies they want, which is what we call the Internet. Some of the companies offer network services as a business, and we call them ISPs, but that is not all the companies that connect to each other, forming the Internet.

Comment: Each RIR maintains its own data, and what and how they offer that to the public is up to the RIR. Remember that we are now in the age of privacy with countries demanding that certain data stay in the country, and that data can be hidden upon request. The EU has some serious penalties for violating its rules. I have no idea how that affects the data presented by the RIRs.